# "404 FILE NOT FOUND" on my username entries

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, security, administration

In Sharepoint 2010 Central Administration --> Security --> Manage the farm admii
nistrator group (Central Administration : Site Settings : People and Groups - Farm Administrators), when I click on my user name, I am getting:

- 404 FILE NOT FOUND

I am under domain user which is part of WSS_Admin_WPG group, owner of site collection.

This is only for my user entry, the others are opening fine.
The user exists. I deleted the entry, then entered my username --> validated (the name became linked and ckicking on it opens my user profile on Sharepoint wo1o Farm) and recreated the user in "Farm Administrators" group.

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I inadvertently deleted "My personal home page"

with entries for

- My Site
  _http://sptest/my/
- My Profile
  _http://sptest/my/Person.aspx?accountname=i%3A0%23%2Ew%7CMyDomain%5CMyUserName

[image]